# Magento 2.0.2 CE doesn't display any stores when I try to create an order through admin area

Tags: magento, admin

I try to place order in `Magento` 2.0.2 CE.

But `Magento` 2.0.2 CE doesn't display any stores when I try to create an order through admin area.

http://joxi.ru/5md7wLNUvnlvRr

Comment: Have you created a store?

Comment: Yes, there are 6 additional stores on Magento 2, and all of them are enabled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Go to System > Manage Stores**

Check if you created a store or not

Comment: Yes, there are 6 additional stores on Magento 2, and all of them are enabled.

Comment: place order from frontend and check

Comment: I have made order from frontend, but it didn't change anything